# Creating an array from multiple columns without NULL elements

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, json, array

I'm trying to build a query to aggregate together multiple columns in a legacy table stored in a similar structure as below:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE foo AS
SELECT * FROM ( VALUES
  (1,'Router','Networking','Sale',NULL),
  (2,NULL,'Router','Networking','Sale'),
  (3,NULL,NULL,'Networking','Sale'),
  (4,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL)
) AS t(id,tag_1,tag_2,tag_3,tag_4);
```

### An example of NOT WHAT I WANT

This is an example of the query I want to build:

```
SELECT ID, json_build_array(Tag_1, Tag_2, Tag_3, Tag_4) AS tags
FROM table
```

The problem is that the **above query adds the NULL values** from the rows to the array:

```
ID  Tags
--------------------------------------------------
1   ['Router', 'Networking', 'Sale', null]
2   [null, 'Router', 'Networking', 'Sale']
3   [null, null, 'Networking', 'Sale']
4   [null, null, null, null]
```

**I want to avoid having to write an overly complicated `CASE WHEN` statement to filter out the NULLs** and I'm still new to working PostgreSQL's JSON datatypes. Is there anyway I can avoid including NULLs when building a JSON array in Postgres?

Comment: You don't say what you want in the case of id=4. To be pruned. You should always show what you want and not what you're currently generating. We tend to skim over this stuff and skip English. Also, study that `CREATE TABLE AS` and try to use that syntax to demonstrate your data in the future. It helps us get up with the DDL and DML needed.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I would suggest not using a JSON array, and instead using the native SQL array syntax which is likely much faster and more efficiently stored. It's also stronger typed. The JSON array is *"possibly-heterogeneously-typed"* per the docs.

I also wouldn't do this routinely. I would alter the table's schema to have an `ARRAY` (preferably SQL) on the table itself to store the tags without ever storing null in columns. This can put you down the path of correcting the schema.

## Building arrays

### Strictly-typed PostgreSQL array

Just use the ARRAY literal constructor.

```
 SELECT id, ARRAY[tag_1,tag_2,tag_3,tag_4] FROM foo;
 id |             array             
----+-------------------------------
  1 | {Router,Networking,Sale,NULL}
  2 | {NULL,Router,Networking,Sale}
  3 | {NULL,NULL,Networking,Sale}
  4 | {NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL}
```

### A JSON array

```
SELECT id, json_build_array(tag_1,tag_2,tag_3,tag_4) FROM foo;
 id |            json_build_array            
----+----------------------------------------
  1 | ["Router", "Networking", "Sale", null]
  2 | [null, "Router", "Networking", "Sale"]
  3 | [null, null, "Networking", "Sale"]
  4 | [null, null, null, null]
(4 rows)
```

## Filtering Nulls without manual `coalesce`

### Strictly-typed PostgreSQL array

You can easily filter nulls in a single pass by wrapping the above in `array_remove`.

```
SELECT id, array_remove(ARRAY[tag_1,tag_2,tag_3,tag_4], null)
FROM foo;

 id |       array_remove       
----+--------------------------
  1 | {Router,Networking,Sale}
  2 | {Router,Networking,Sale}
  3 | {Networking,Sale}
  4 | {}
```

### JSON array

```
SELECT id,jsonb_agg(elem)
FROM (SELECT id, ARRAY[tag_1,tag_2,tag_3,tag_4] FROM foo) AS g
CROSS JOIN LATERAL unnest(g.array)
  WITH ORDINALITY AS t(elem,ord)
WHERE elem IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY id;

 id |            jsonb_agg             
----+----------------------------------
  1 | ["Router", "Networking", "Sale"]
  2 | ["Router", "Networking", "Sale"]
  3 | ["Networking", "Sale"]
```

Comment: Thanks, I went with the PostgreSQL array solution and wrapped the query to remove the empty array. This was my resulting solution `SELECT a.id, CASE WHEN a.tags = '{}' THEN NULL ELSE array_to_json(a.tags) END FROM (SELECT id, array_remove(ARRAY[tag_1,tag_2,tag_3,tag_4], null) AS tags FROM foo) a`

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
SELECT 
    id, 
    ( SELECT json_agg(tag ORDER BY no) 
      FROM 
        ( SELECT 1, tag_1 UNION ALL 
          SELECT 2, tag_2 UNION ALL 
          SELECT 3, tag_3 UNION ALL
          SELECT 4, tag_4
        )  AS x (no, tag)
      WHERE tag IS NOT NULL
    ) AS tags 
FROM t  ;
```